# What model and year is this bike?

Tags: mountain-bike, frames, identify-this-bike, cannondale

[image]What model and year is this bike? Stickers/Decals say Cannondale but not 100% sure if it is.

I have looked at catalogues of cannondale from 1997 to 2010 and can't see this bike.  If anyone could help I would be really thankful.its frame number is A9H64776 if this helps

Comment: its frame number is A9H64776

Answer (score 1):

If that's a Cannondale, it is a Chase, probably a Chase "2".

http://www.bikepedia.com/Search.aspx?Q=cannondale%20chase

Comment: thanks for your answer , i thought that it was a chase too but frame looks different

Comment: Yeah, the Chase is the only range they made where the top tube forms a straight line with the seat stays.  The headset, stem and squared chain stays are also a good clue.

Comment: This frame has visible weld beads. All Cannondales I have seen have very distinctive smooth sanded welds. Also, the lack of model name sticker is a bit suspicious.

Comment: @ojs this is what I thought but any ideas on what make it could be?

Comment: Those are very early model cable brakes and the shocks with bolt on arch and crown predate the Chase by 4-6 years.

Comment: The fork is a Marzocchi Bomber Z1 CR - Could be as early as 1997, most likely with the discs it will be late 90's.

Comment: do you think it is a cannondale though?

Comment: No - welds, rear drop outs and top tube/steerer intersection do not match any Chase I have seen, or any on internet search. I don't think Cannondale ever shipped with Marzocchi shocks (please correct me if I am wrong on this).

Comment: I have found out it is definitely not a cannondale so can anyone throw any light which make it could be?

Comment: There are at least hundreds of different aluminium frames. Good luck trying to find what matches... My guess would be "some generic Taiwanese or mainland Chinese frame, probably directly from alibaba.com"

Comment: you in the r.a.f. ?